# When escalating from a change of style in With Great Power, what card has to be played?

Tags: with-great-power

When running a conflict in **With Great Power**, I'm a bit confused as to what cards have to be played after the style has been changed.  Let's take an example first three panels:

GM -> Player

7 Hearts -> (escalate) 8 Hearts

9 Hearts -> (change of style to clubs) 4 & 5 Clubs

(Changing style back to hearts) 4 & 5 Hearts -> ??????

My question is, if the player wants to escalate, can they use a 6 of Hearts (thus beating the 4 that was last played), or do they have to play a 10 of hearts or higher to get the ranking card for that page?  The rules are clear on the point that you can change the style if you have the ranking card in the suit you're changing to, but is a bit light on what happens after the fact.

Comment: +1 for a Q about *With Great Power*. This may prompt me to pull my copy off the shelf in an effort to answer you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the GM changes back to hearts, the 9 of hearts is the ranking card, even though she played the 4 & 5 of hearts to make hearts the active suit. The player will need to play a 10 or higher of hearts to escalate, cancel the 9 of hearts, or change suit.

In the same way, if the player chooses to change suit back to clubs and plays the 2 & 3 of clubs, the 3 will be discarded as the "price" to change suit. The 2 will be set on the page, and the 4 will be the ranking card. The GM will have to play a 5 or higher of clubs to escalate.

Each suit is kinda like its own ladder. Only the card on the highest rung matters. The cards on the lower rungs only ever matter if the highest card is cancelled. There's no other way to move down in value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did I miss something? Shouldn't the ranking card in the second paragraph be a "5 of clubs" as 2+3? (also know that I'm only adding and and don't have the rules. `:)` )